# Json: if category id matches the parent number, put category under neath parent category

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to put the child category under the parent category, if the parent category id # matches the parent # I want to display below the parent category. if you look below you will see that category id #1 is the parent and sub categories have "parent: 1" for value. I hope this makes sense if you need me to clarity let me know.

jquery code:

```
// get categories lists
function listCategories(data) {
  "use strict";
  var output = '<ul data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" >';
  $.each(data.categories, function(key, val) {
    if (val.id == val.parent) {

        output += '<li><a href="#'+ val.slug + '">' + val.title + '+</a></li>';
    }else if (val.id !== val.parent) {

  output += '<li><a href="#'+ val.slug + '">' + val.title + '-</a></li>';
    }

  }); //go through each list item
  output += '</ul>';
  $('#postlist').html(output);

}
```

json code:

```
"status": "ok",
    "count": 7,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "slug": "all-qualified-retirement-plans",
            "title": "All Qualified Retirement Plans",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 1,
            "post_count": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "slug": "defined-benefit-db-plans",
            "title": "Defined Benefit (DB) Plans",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 1,
            "post_count": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "slug": "defined-contribution-and-hybrid-plans",
            "title": "Defined Contribution and Hybrid Plans",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 1,
            "post_count": 6
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "slug": "fica-ss-medicare-taxes",
            "title": "FICA - SS &amp; MEDICARE TAXES",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "slug": "healthcare-plans",
            "title": "Healthcare Plans",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "slug": "other-benefits",
            "title": "Other Benefits",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "retirement-plans",
            "title": "Retirement Plans",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 13
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy hack is to reorder the `li` elements after those are added to the dom like

```js
// get categories lists
function listCategories(data) {
  "use strict";
  var output = '<ul data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" >';
  $.each(data.categories, function(key, val) {
    output += '<li data-id="' + val.id + '" data-parent="' + val.parent + '"><a href="#' + val.slug + '">' + val.title + '+</a></li>';
  }); //go through each list item
  output += '</ul>';
  var $ul = $(output);

  $ul.children().each(function() {
    var parent = $(this).data('parent');
    var $li = $ul.find('li[data-id="' + parent + '"]');
    if ($li.length) {
      var $cul = $li.find('ul');
      if (!$cul.length) {
        $cul = $('<ul/>').appendTo($li);
      }
      $cul.append(this)
    }
  });
  $ul.find('li:has(ul) > a').contents().unwrap();

  $('#postlist').html($ul);

}

var data = {
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 7,
  "categories": [{
    "id": 4,
    "slug": "all-qualified-retirement-plans",
    "title": "All Qualified Retirement Plans",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 1,
    "post_count": 4
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "slug": "defined-benefit-db-plans",
    "title": "Defined Benefit (DB) Plans",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 1,
    "post_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "slug": "defined-contribution-and-hybrid-plans",
    "title": "Defined Contribution and Hybrid Plans",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 1,
    "post_count": 6
  }, {
    "id": 7,
    "slug": "fica-ss-medicare-taxes",
    "title": "FICA - SS &amp; MEDICARE TAXES",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 0,
    "post_count": 4
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "slug": "healthcare-plans",
    "title": "Healthcare Plans",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 0,
    "post_count": 5
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "slug": "other-benefits",
    "title": "Other Benefits",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 0,
    "post_count": 3
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "retirement-plans",
    "title": "Retirement Plans",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 0,
    "post_count": 13
  }]
};

listCategories(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="postlist"></div>
```

Comment: this works,  but I need to disable the <a> tag if it has sub categories

Comment: @velvetInk what do you mean by disable?

Comment: @velvetInk whether you don't want to have the anchor elements in the sub categories?

Comment: disable the parent if it has sub categories

Answer (score 0):

The most clean method I could think of was ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pn37o2s3/6/)):

First map the parent-children relations. Then print the tree you want to display in a recursive manner. This even enables more levels in your tree. It doesn't add more DOM operations than necessary

```
function listCategories(data) {
  "use strict";
  var output = '<ul data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" >';
  var children = {};
  var dataById = {};

  // Map parent-children relations
  $.each(data.categories, function(key, val) {
    (children[val.parent] = children[val.parent] || []).push(val.id);
    dataById[val.id] = val;
  });

  // Work recursive through the tree 
  var printRecursive = function(id) {
    var subs = "";
    $.each(children[id] || [], function(key, val) {
      subs += printRecursive(val);
    });
    if (dataById[id]) {
      var hasChildren = subs != "";
      var result = "<li>"
      if(hasChildren) {
        result += dataById[id].title;
        result += "<ul>" + subs + "</ul>";
      } else {
        result += '<a href="#' + dataById[id].slug + '">' + dataById[id].title + '</a>';
      }
      result += "</li>";
      return result;
    }

    return subs;
  };
  // Print tree with root 'id=0'
  $('#postlist').html('<ul data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" >' + printRecursive(0, 0) + '</ul');
}
```

This does the job.

Updated: no link on parent.

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: get

Comment: this works but is there a way to disable the <a> if it has sub categories?

Comment: disable the parent if it has sub categories